# Can tomorrow be the subject of a sentence with a past tense verb?

Tags: verbs, tenses, subjects

Tomorrow was the annual harvest fair  --  the biggest event of the year.

Comment: Unrelated dumb question...why is the festival both in the future and the past?  :-/

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please consider editing your question to make the context of the sentence clear. It only makes sense if the narrative is taking place in the past?

Comment: I can think of one situation in which this sentence would work.

Comment: There is a way in which the past tense would work, though it is rare and a special case.  You are going over your commitments for the week with your assistant.  But you are not paying attention.  You are worried about a sick child at home.  So you ask: “What was tomorrow, again?”. And the assistant replies:  “Tomorrow was the harvest festival. Weren’t you listening?”  In this special usage what is past is not tomorrow’s harvest festival but the assistant’s mention of it.  Strange, but possible.

Comment: (1) He said "I'll do that job tomorrow," but tomorrow came and went.  (2) Tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow crept in this petty pace from day to day.

Answer (score -1):

[This article from Education first](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/changing-time-and-place-references/) [shortened and reformatted] explains the underlying grammar:

> **Changing time and place references ...**
>
> *Time and place must often change when going from direct to reported speech.*
>
> **today ...   that day**
>
> Phrase in direct speech: "I saw him today", she said.
>
> Equivalent in reported speech: She said that she had seen him that
>   day.
>
> ........
>
> **yesterday ...   the day before**
>
> Phrase in direct speech: "I saw him yesterday", she said.
>
> Equivalent in reported speech: She said that she had seen him the day
>   before.
>
> .......
>
> **tomorrow    the next/following day**
>
> Phrase in direct speech: "I'll see you tomorrow", he said
>
> Equivalent in reported speech: She said that she would see him the
>   next/following day.

However, thoughts (recorded 'verbatim' or paraphrased, from either the character being referenced or the narrator, so grading into notions) do not demand inverted commas, so

*Tomorrow would be the annual harvest fair – the biggest event of the year.*

is acceptable.